# Append as array inside array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, vue.js, vuejs2

I have an object that looks like this, and I can push data using below method. Also I initialize the `types` data.

```
myObj = {
    1: ["a", "b", "c"],
    2: ["c", "d", "e"],
}
```

---

```
data: {
   types: {}
},

methods: {

  pushValue(key, value) {
      var obj = this.types

      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          var idx = $.inArray(value, obj[key]);
          if (idx == -1) {
             obj[key].push([value]);
          }
      } else {
          this.$set(obj, key, [value]);
      }
  },
}
```

It works fine.

---

However, now I want my object to look like this:

```
myObj = {
    1: {
        "a": [
           [],[]
        ], 
        "b": [
           [],[]
        ],
       }
 }
```

How can I modify my append function to append the elements like this?

Comment: Can you share more about what's the object output?? I don't quite understand what's `"a" => [ ... ]` and I don't quite know where exactly do you want to push your value in the new output using `pushValue`

Comment: I am getting key and value on a `@change` on checkboxes. `@change`, push value is triggeted with key: 1 or 2, value: a,b,c, etc. And I edited obj to myObj for not confusing it with the one within the method

Comment: So what exactly do you want to store inside `"myObj.1.a`?? And is there relationship between `this.types` and `myObj`? Because I don't see `myObj` has anything to do with `pushValue`.

Comment: I just want it to be there, even as an empty array. So that I can use it in in v-for and using index, I can understand its count; to be able to use in `:name` attributes of child component

Comment: Then what exactly will you push into `myObj.1.a` then? I mean, what will be pushed into the empty arrays? The numbers 1 or 2, or the keys a, b, c, ...? Because when you execute `pushValues`, you are modifying `this.types`, not `myObj`. Even at this moment I still don't quite know what's the point of `myObj`. Or you just want to append an array with two empty arrays inside to `myObj.1.a`??

Comment: Yes, I don't want to modify myObj. I want to modify this.types instead. myObj is just to show the structure of the object. I will not push anything inside these values, I just want to know the count and which index it has so that I can use it in `:name` attribute for the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm just answering this according my assumption of what @senty is trying to do:

pushValue is a method that takes numbers as `key`s and characters as `value`s and save them into `this.types`, and whenever `pushValue` is called, `this.types` is gonna have a property `key` storing an object with `value` as its key, which stores an array containing an empty array. If That array (the one that contains arrays) already exists, another empty is gonna appended to that array. And eventually `this.types` will look like `myObj`

Hence, `pushValue` should look like this:

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    types: {}
  },
  methods: {
    pushValue(key, value) {
      if (this.types.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        if (this.types[key].hasOwnProperty(value)) {
          const orgValue = this.types[key][value];
          orgValue.push([]);
          this.$set(this.types[key], value, orgValue);
        } else {
          this.$set(this.types[key], value, [[]]);
        }
      } else {
        this.$set(this.types, key, {
          [value]: [ [] ]
        });
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <p>pushValue(key, value)</p>
    <button v-on:click="pushValue(1, 'a')">(1, 'a')</button>
    <button v-on:click="pushValue(1, 'b')">(1, 'b')</button>
    <button v-on:click="pushValue(1, 'c')">(1, 'c')</button>
    <button v-on:click="pushValue(2, 'a')">(2, 'a')</button>
    <button v-on:click="pushValue(2, 'b')">(2, 'b')</button>
    <button v-on:click="pushValue(2, 'c')">(2, 'c')</button>
  </div>
  <div>{{ types }}</div>  
</div>
```

Comment: @senty please let me know if this is what you want

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's really good except one thing. For the else part, in Vue, if you don't use `.$set`, it changes the value (i can see it in debugger), but it won't create the component on the view or execute any v-for which this variable is used in. Can you please show me how to use $set in the else part, with your approach? (I run this problem for the last 2 days so I am kind of sure that it is it)

Comment: @senty Just modified the code snippet into using Vue and also Vue.$set, everything should be working now.