# Watching nested object data from parent

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a nested object in my parent data and it looks like this.

```
obj: {
   1: {
     'a': [ [], [], [] ]
     'b': [ [] ]
   },
   2: {
     'x': [ [], [] ]
   }
}
```

While initialising, in data in my parent, I initialise this `obj` as `{}`. When I try using a watcher in my child component, it only watches the 1, 2 key levels and not when changes happen to letter key levels. However, I want it to get executed even when changes happen in inner levels.

```
// in my component
computed: {
    watchForms() {
        alert("X");
    }
},
```

Then, I tried to use emit/on to tell from root element to child when new element is added/removed to the object - emit the event and catch it on the component.

```
// So I set a global variable,
Vue.prototype.globalEvents = new Vue();

// In my root element, initialised the obj
data: {
   obj: {}
} 

// In my root element methods, when changes happen on my obj
methods: {
   changeHappened() {
     this.globalEvents.$emit('updated');
   }
}

// And in my component, I tried to catch it and run the method,
created: function() {
    this.globalEvents.$on('updated', this.watchForms);
},
```

> [Vue warn]: Error in event handler for "updated": "TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined" (found in )

I receive this error however I don't call any `.apply()` :/ What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It seems `this.watchForms` is undefined in `created()` as an argument to  `$on( ... )`

Comment: What is the right way of doing it? Isn't it supposed to get triggered every time some changes happen in obj?

Answer (score 0):

Previously I have answered your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45490641/append-as-array-inside-array/45491179#45491179) which this question seems to be relevant, so I'm just gonna modify the same snippet I used illustrating by using `deep: true` and you'll able to watch nested properties:

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    types: {},
    history: []
  },
  watch: {
    types: {
      handler(newVal) {
        this.history.push(JSON.stringify(newVal));
      },
      deep: true
    }
  },
  methods: {
    pushValue(key, value) {
      if (this.types.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        if (this.types[key].hasOwnProperty(value)) {
          const orgValue = this.types[key][value];
          orgValue.push([]);
          this.$set(this.types[key], value, orgValue);
        } else {
          this.$set(this.types[key], value, [[]]);
        }
      } else {
        this.$set(this.types, key, {
          [value]: [ [] ]
        });
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <p>pushValue(key, value)</p>
    <button v-on:click="pushValue(1, 'a')">(1, 'a')</button>
    <button v-on:click="pushValue(1, 'b')">(1, 'b')</button>
    <button v-on:click="pushValue(1, 'c')">(1, 'c')</button>
    <button v-on:click="pushValue(2, 'a')">(2, 'a')</button>
    <button v-on:click="pushValue(2, 'b')">(2, 'b')</button>
    <button v-on:click="pushValue(2, 'c')">(2, 'c')</button>
  </div>
  <div>types:</div>
  <div>{{ types }}</div>
  <div>modified:</div>
  <div v-for="item in history">{{ item }}</div>
</div>
```